# If string matches any words in an array then replace with numbers

Tags: php

I have a string `$str` that contains a large amount of text. I want to replace specific words in that string with numbers.

Is there a way to run through the string and if any words match any in an array then replace it with the corresponding number like so:

- Rob => 1
- Tom => 7
- Lee => 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array with str_replace()

```
$str = str_replace(['Rob','Tom','Lee'],[1,7,5],$str);
```